# Angular 2 show and hide button component

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a button (that opens a dialog component) either the current user is admin or not. The problem is that I cannot figure out how.

This is my html of my component:

```
<app-list [items]="items"
  [page]="'1'"
  [itemsPerPage]="'40'"
  [hasPager]="false"
  [hasFilters]="false"
  [itemInfo]="itemInfo"
  [loading]="loading"
  (onAdd)="handleOnAdd($event)"  -> this one renders the button
  (onMenuItem)="handleOnMenuItem($event)">
</app-list>
```

In app-list component:

```
<app-add-button *ngIf="itemInfo.types"
  [hasPager]="hasPager"
  (onAction)="onAdd.emit($event)">
</app-add-button>

// .ts
  @Output() onAdd = new EventEmitter();
```

What I wanted is to do something like this:

```
  [loading]="loading"
  *ngIf="loggedUser.coachAdmin"
  (onAdd)="handleOnAdd($event)"
  (onMenuItem)="handleOnMenuItem($event)">
```

To display the button(or at least making it functional) only if the user is a admin. There is such a way? Or at least how to solve it?

Comment: which part  you cannot figure it out?

Comment: It's not working to add the ngIf(see last piece of code), so wasn't sure how to handle it.

Comment: please show us your full code, a stackblitz would be better

Comment: The project is huge, I cannot separate things. I am just curious if I can write the ngIf as to show/hide the (onAdd)="handleOnAdd($event)"

Comment: ok, I assume you can extract relevant piece of code into a stackblitz and thus can be checked and verified easily. but never mind :)

Comment: :P thank you either way

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if coachAdmin is a boolean variable. If not, you would have to change your ngIf to look something like this:

```
*ngIf="loggedUser.coachAdmin==='ADMIN'"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question in the comments:

> I am just curious if I can write the ngIf as to show/hide the (onAdd)="handleOnAdd($event)"

No, you can't use `*ngIf` to "show/hide" the `(onAdd)` attribute.

If you want to show/hide the component, then the code you posted (`*ngIf="loggedUser.coachAdmin"`) should work fine.

If, however, you want to conditionally execute some code (depending on if user is admin or not), then you should handle that inside your component class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way by using [hidden]

```
[hidden]="loggedUser.coachAdmin !== 'ADMIN'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *display* the button only for admins, just add it as a condition in the `*ngIf`:

```
<app-add-button *ngIf="itemInfo.types && loggedUser.coachAdmin"
  [hasPager]="hasPager"
  (onAction)="onAdd.emit($event)">
</app-add-button>
```

If you want it to be *functional* only for admins, the shortest way would be to do it with a short-circuit logic check:

```
<app-add-button *ngIf="itemInfo.types"
  [hasPager]="hasPager"
  (onAction)="loggedUser.coachAdmin && onAdd.emit($event)">
</app-add-button>
```